# Rank 3 tensor multiplies with a rank two tensor in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have a question about multiplication in Tensorflow; I have a rank 3 tensor A and a rank 2 tensor B, how can I get a rank 3 tensor C with each element in first dimension of C the multiplications between every matrix in A (first dimension) and tensor B? 
Eg:

```
A= [[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[7,8]]]
B = [[2,3],[4,5]]
```

I want to finally get a rank 3 tensor C:

```
C = [A[:,0,0]*B,A[1,:0,:]*B] 
  = [[[1,2],[3,4]]*B,[[5,6],[7,8]]*B]
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem can be solved using tf.matmul. I can repeat B for m times which is equal to the first dimension of A; then C =tf.matmul(A,B); i.e., new B is defined as:

```
B=[B,B]=[[[2,3],[4,5]],[[2,3],[4,5]]]
```

The dimension of B is [2,2,2] and dimension of A is [2,2,2,], tf.matmul(A,B) will conduct component-wise multiplication(each component is a 2 by 2 tensor) and results in C which has dimension [2,2,2]